# Why does a partial application have value restriction?

Tags: ocaml

I can understand that `allowing mutable` is the reason for value restriction and weakly polymorphism. Basically a mutable ref inside a function may change the type involved and affect the future use of the function. So real polymorphism may not be introduced in case of type mismatch.

For example,

```
# let remember =
    let cache = ref None in
    (fun x ->
       match !cache with
       | Some y -> y
       | None -> cache := Some x; x)
  ;;
val remember : '_a -> '_a = <fun>
```

In remember, cache originally was `'a option`, but once it gets called first time `let () = remember 1`, cache turns to be `int option`, thus the type becomes limited. Value restriction solves this potential problem.

---

What I still don't understand is the value restriction on partial application.

For example,

```
let identity x = x
val identity: 'a -> 'a = <fun>

let map_rep = List.map identity
val map_rep: '_a list -> '_a list = <fun>
```

in the functions above, I don't see any ref or mutable place, why still value restriction is applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good paper that describes OCaml's current handling of the value restriction:

> [Garrigue, Relaxing the Value Restriction](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf)

It has a good capsule summary of the problem and its history.

Here are some observations, for what they're worth. I'm not an expert, just an amateur observer:

1. The meaning of "value" in the term "value restriction" is highly technical, and isn't directly related to the values manipulated by a particular language. It's a *syntactic* term; i.e., you can recognize values by just looking at the symbols of the program, without knowing anything about types.
2. It's not hard at all to produce examples where the value restriction is too restrictive. I.e., where it would be safe to generalize a type when the value restriction forbids it. But attempts to do a better job (to allow more generalization) resulted in rules that were too difficult to remember and follow for mere mortals (such as myself).
3. The impediment to generalizing exactly when it would be safe to do so is not separate compilation (IMHO) but the halting problem. I.e., it's not possible in theory even if you see all the program text.

Answer (score 2):

The value restriction is pretty simple: only let-bound expressions that are syntactically values are generalized. Applications, including partial applications, are not values and thus are not generalized.

Note that in general it is impossible to tell whether an application is partial, and thus whether the application could have an effect on the value of a reference cell. Of course in this particular case it is obvious that no such thing occurs, but the inference rules are designed to be sound in the event that it does.

Comment: ok, i thought value restriction is applied when compiler sees ref or detect any mutable. Could you please tell me in my first `remember` example, it is a let-bound, isn't it? Also, why was compiler not built in the way to detect `ref` or mutable and then apply value restriction?

Comment: Well, being let-bound is not enough to be polymorphic. It also has to be a "syntactic value". As for the second, I imagine the concern was for separate compilation. If the knowledge of whether `Foo.f` involved manipulating a reference had to be passed around to compile sources that used `Foo.f`, that would break separate compilation quite badly.

Comment: for the second, in your example `Foo.f`, if `Foo.f` has a `ref`, then `Foo.f` will value restricted already, and for other compilation involving `Foo.f` naturally knows it from its signature, isn't it?

Comment: but anyway, could you please give me an example for partial application just like I did as the `remember` example?

Comment: Jackson, an example is given in the paper linked by seanmcl: search for `evil_map`.

Answer (score 2):

A 'let' expression is not a (syntactic) value.  While there is a [precise definition](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/values.html) of 'value', roughly the only values are identifiers, functions, constants, and constructors applied to values.

[This paper](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf) and those it references explains the problem in detail.

Comment: but is `remember` function a value?

Comment: The let expression 'evaluates' to a value, which is a function with type '_a -> '_a.  The resulting value is bound to the identifier  'remember'.  Thereafter, remember is a value, being that it is a syntactic identifier, and thus a value.

Comment: could you please give me an example for partial application just like I did as the `remember` example?

Answer (score 1):

Partial application doesn't preclude mutation. For example, here is a refactored version of your code that would also be incorrect without value restriction:

```
let aux cache x =
    match !cache with
    | Some y -> y
    | None -> cache := Some x; x

let remember = aux (ref None)
```