# On defining list length in terms of fold

Tags: ocaml

This is just an exercise (I realize that the functions mentioned below are already implemented in `List`).

Suppose that I have an interface that includes the following lines

```
val length : 'a list -> int
val fold   : init:'acc -> f:('acc -> 'a -> 'acc) -> 'a list -> 'acc
```

...and that I implement `fold` like this:

```
let rec fold ~init ~f l =
  match l with
  | []     -> init
  | h :: t -> fold ~init:(f init h) ~f:f t
```

I expected to now be able to implement `length` like this

```
let length = fold ~init:0 ~f:(fun c _ -> (c + 1))
```

...but the compiler complains with

```
   Values do not match:
     val length : '_a list -> int
   is not included in
     val length : 'a list -> int
```

Of course, I know that I can implement `length` like this

```
let length l = fold ~init:0 ~f:(fun c _ -> (c + 1)) l
```

...but I don't understand why I can't remove the trailing `l` from both sides of the `=`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the value restriction. Your definition of length is not a value in a very technical sense. There are some good discussions of the issue already here on Stack Overflow. I'll look for a good one.

Here is a pretty good one:

> [Why does a partial application have value restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278914/why-does-a-partial-application-have-value-restriction)

Comment: It's not *that* deep :-) The capsule summary is that you can't make things polymorphic unless you're sure it's safe. In a language with mutable data (such as OCaml) it's not always safe. The "value restriction" is an approximation of when it's safe. It's not a particularly close approximation, but it's easy to remember.

Comment: I have a "short brain", I guess, because it's not at all obvious to me that the "value restriction" would be a solution (let alone a good one) to the problem of implementing type inference in a language that supports polymorphic types and mutable data.  BTW, I wish that the designers of OCaml had not settled for easy-to-remember, and gone instead for greatest expressive power; after all, the whole point of using computers is to go beyond what we can do in our heads.

Comment: Read this article for some background: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf. The cost/benefit tradeoffs of the value restriction are excellent (IMHO). OCaml has relaxed the value restriction to allow more polymorphism.

Comment: @kjo There was a [very influential paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/fps/papers/wright.ps.gz) in the 90s which analysed 250,000 lines of existing Standard ML code (which at the time had a more expressive restriction) and showed that in the vast majority of cases the value restriction did not make things any less expressive. Since then the value restriction has been almost universally adopted in languages with polymorphism and mutation.